# Permutation-based alternative to scipy.stats.ttest_1samp

Tags: python, scipy, permutation, t-test, scipy.stats

I would like to use a permutation-based alternative to [`scipy.stats.ttest_1samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html) to test if the mean of my observations is significantly greater than zero.
I stumbled upon [`scipy.stats.permutation_test`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.permutation_test.html) but I am not sure if this can also be used in my case? I also stumbled upon [`mne.stats.permutation_t_test`](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.stats.permutation_t_test.html) which seems to do what I want, but I would like to stick to `scipy` if I can.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# create data
np.random.seed(42)
rvs = np.random.normal(loc=5,scale=5,size=100)

# compute one-sample t-test 
t,p = stats.ttest_1samp(rvs,popmean=0,alternative='greater')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test can be performed with `permutation_test`. With `permutation_type='samples'`, it "permutes" the signs of the observations. Assuming data has been generated as above, the test can be performed as

```py
from scipy import stats
def t_statistic(x, axis=-1):
    return stats.ttest_1samp(x, popmean=0, axis=axis).statistic

res = stats.permutation_test((rvs,), t_statistic, permutation_type='samples')
print(res.pvalue)
```

If you only care about the p-value, you can get the same result with `np.mean` as the statistic instead of `t_statistic`.

Admittedly, this behavior for `permutation_type='samples'` with only one sample is a bit buried in the documentation.

> Accordingly, if data contains only one sample, then the null distribution is formed by independently changing the sign of each observation.

But a test producing the same p-value could also be performed as a two-sample test in which the second sample is the negative of the data. To avoid special cases, that's actually what `permutation_test` does under the hood.

In this case, the example code above is a lot faster than `permutation_test` right now. I'll try to improve that for SciPy 1.10, though.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the current [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.permutation_test.html), it does not appear that the equivalent of a one-sample t-test is achievable with the `permutation_test` function.  But it's possible to implement it using `numpy`, as shown below.  This is based on the R implementation (found [here](https://github.com/cran/DAAG/blob/master/R/onetPermutation.R)) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65831/permutation-test-comparing-a-single-sample-against-a-mean) thread on Cross Validated, with options to do a one-sided test and a test against a specific mean added.

```
import numpy as np

def permutation_ttest_1samp(
    data, popmean, n_resamples, alternative='two-sided', random_state=None
):

    assert alternative in ('two-sided', 'less', 'greater'), (
        "Unrecognized alternative hypothesis"
    )

    n = len(data)

    data = np.asarray(data) - popmean
    dbar = np.mean(data)
    
    absx = np.abs(data)
    z = []

    rng = np.random.RandomState(random_state)

    for _ in range(n_resamples):
        mn = rng.choice((-1,1), n, replace=True)
        xbardash = np.mean(mn * absx)
        z.append(xbardash)
    z = np.array(z)

    if alternative == 'greater':
        return 1 - (np.sum(z <= -np.abs(dbar)) / n_resamples)
    elif alternative == 'less':
        return np.sum(z <= -np.abs(dbar)) / n_resamples
    return (
        (np.sum(z >= np.abs(dbar)) + np.sum(z <= -np.abs(dbar))) / n_resamples
    )
```

Example 1 (two-sided test against null hypothesis of mean 0):

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
rvs = rng.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01, size=1000)

pval = permutation_ttest_1samp(rvs, 0, 100_000, alternative='two-sided', random_state=42)
print(pval)
# 0.53206
```

Comparing to parameterized t-test:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp

stat, pval = ttest_1samp(rvs, popmean=0, alternative='two-sided')
print(pval)
# 0.5325672436623021
```

Example 2 (one-sided test against a non-0 mean null hypothesis)

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
rvs = rng.normal(loc=0, scale=3, size=1000)

pval = permutation_ttest_1samp(rvs, 0.1, 100_000, alternative='greater', random_state=42)
print(pval)
# 0.6731
```

Comparing to parameterized t-test:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp

stat, pval = ttest_1samp(rvs, popmean=0.1, alternative='greater')
print(pval)
# 0.6743729530216749
```

Comment: Ha! Interesting, that this does not have been implemented in scipy. Do you think it would make sense to open an issue for that on Github? Thanks for the code! In case you have time: I would love to also obtain a t-value, maybe you could also implement that in your function?

Comment: I have not found a reference for how to compute the test statistic with this test, so I'm inclined to leave the test statistic computation to others. I just corrected how the p-value for the 'greater' test is computed, to match what's done in a standard t-test.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16962) on Github